# Arrays - Multiple Files Upload - Delete Parent Array Element Where Child Array ['error'] => 4

Tags: php, arrays, function, if-statement, multidimensional-array

Here is my code:

**HTML (Multiple Uploads):**

```
<input type="file" name="attached_photo_1" id="attached_photo_1" />
<input type="file" name="attached_photo_2" id="attached_photo_2" />
<input type="file" name="attached_photo_3" id="attached_photo_3" />
<input type="file" name="attached_photo_4" id="attached_photo_4" />
<input type="file" name="attached_photo_5" id="attached_photo_5" />
```

**PHP**

```
$photo_array = array( 
  $_FILES['attached_photo_1'], 
  $_FILES['attached_photo_2'], 
  $_FILES['attached_photo_3'],
  $_FILES['attached_photo_4'],
  $_FILES['attached_photo_5']
);
```

**Example**

Now lets say someone only uploaded images for photo 1 and 2, leaving images 3, 4, and 5 with a $_FILES error code of 4 (meaning no file was uploaded).

**Example Output** (using `<?php print_r($photo_array); ?>`):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => test.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/php0JwXJc
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 3469655
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => test-2.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpv7qFc6
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 1666451
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

---

**MAIN QUESTION:**
How Can I remove all of the parent array elements where the child array's `[error] => 4`?  Thus in the example above elements [2], [3], and [4] would be deleted or unset from the array.

Comment: You are going to be much better off using: `name="attached_photo[]"` and getting an array in PHP when submitted.

Answer (score 0):

At least give it a try. See the following pseudocode to how to acheive this.

```
foreach($photo_array as $key => $values){

       if(isset($key['name']))
           $photo_array[$key] = $values;
       }
    }
```